# Как задать координаты курсора?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть сайт, есть курсор,  и есть скрипт:

```js
document.onmousemove = function(e) {
  var event = e || window.event;
  mouseX = event.clientX;
  mouseY = event.clientY;
  console.log(mouseX + ' x ' + mouseY);
}
```

этот скрипт показывает координаты в консоли.

надо написать скрипт, что бы сайт думал, что курсор находиться в определенных координатах, пример 273,20 при нажатии кнопки на клавиатуры, курсор перемещается на 273,20 так должен думать сайт.

Comment: Он будет так думать, только тогда, когда вы переместите курсор на `273,20`, никогда больше

Comment: Слава богу, что сайты не умеют управлять курсором :)

Answer (score 0):

Если у Вас есть возможность выполнить javascript на этой странице (например через консоль разработчика), то можно просто переназначить обработчик `onmousemove` на тот, который будет передавать дальше необходимую Вам координату, как то так:

```js
document.onmousemove = function(e) {
  someAction(273, 20)
}
```

```html
<script>
document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    var event = e || window.event;
    mouseX = event.clientX;
    mouseY = event.clientY;
    someAction(mouseX, mouseY);
} 

function someAction(x,y) {
    console.log(x, 'x', y);
}
</script>
```